# Looping through MySQL Databases on Single Server in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, loops

I'm trying to loop through all of the databases on one server and replace sensitive information with `"****"` in one table that each of the databases share in PHP. I know I could connect to each database individually and then run the rest of the script, but that would be a painfully long code file as I have over 90 databases on this server. How would I write PHP code that can loop through all of the databases and just have the one action of replacing in all rows? I can do it with a singular database just fine:

```
<?php
$host = 'example.example.com';
$user = 'example';
$password = 'password';
$db = 'database1';

$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

if (!$connection){
    die('Could not connec to server: '.mysqli_error($connection));
}

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `info`"; // The table
$query1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);

if (!$query1){
    die('Could not select from `info`: '.mysqli_error($connection));
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    $id = $row['id'];

    $sql2 = "UPDATE `info`
                 SET `sensitiveinfo1` = '****', `sensitiveinfo2` = '****'
                 WHERE `id` = '$id'";

    $query2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);

    if (!$query2){
        die('Could not replace info with "****": '.mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}
?>
```

So how would I change this to run through all of the databases instead of just one?

Comment: Add an array of database details then do a foreach.

Comment: Could you please provide some code so I can see what you are talking about?

Comment: No, this is not a code writing service. If you don't know how to write a simple foreach pay a professional to do it for you.

Comment: I am learning and have provided the code I started with. What I want to know is how to modify it to make it correct, which is entirely why Stack Overflow exists..

Comment: As Styphon said, define an array wich elements are details to connect to each database, then do a foreach over that array. Inside the foreach, just put your code to do the work on a database.

Comment: just loop through a "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name not in ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema');"  Just add the schema you aren't interested in to the "not in" list and then loop through it.

Comment: Are you looping through 90 databases? Or 90 tables? And if so, are all tables structured the same way (names, types) to run the same update query?

Comment: 90 databases, 1 table per database

Comment: OK - I looked at your code a bit more carefully.  You don't actually need the query you are using at all, nor do you need to iterate through the loop as the query contains no where clause - you are processing all rows in the table.  In addition, you aren't using any transactional controls.  So, your statement would be "update 'info' set `sensitiveinfo1` = '****', `sensitiveinfo2` = '****'".  This will get all rows.  The way you were doing it is far more expensive.  So, change the outer query to the one I suggested above and then for each DB run the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  I'm not much of a PHPer, though.

```
<?php
$host = 'example.example.com';
$user = 'example';
$password = 'password';
$db = 'database1';

$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

if (!$connection){
    die('Could not connect to server: '.mysqli_error($connection));
}

$sql1 = "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema not in ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema)" and table_name = 'info'; // The table
$query1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);

if (!$query1){
    die('Could not select from `information_schema.schemata`: '.mysqli_error($connection));
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    $schema = $row['table_schema'];

    $sql2 = "UPDATE ".$schema.".info SET `sensitiveinfo1` = '****', `sensitiveinfo2` = '****'";


    $query2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);

    if (!$query2){
        die('Could not replace '.$schema.'.info with "****": '.mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}
?>
```